# How to compile BitcoinJS for browsers

Tags: compilation, browserify, bitcoin

I'm trying to compile BitcoinJS library to include it in browser with

```
<script src="js/bitcoinjs.js"></script>
```

I'm trying all day but I couldn't.
What I do is to follow the instructions

```
npm -g install bitcoinjs-lib browserify
browserify bitcoinjs-lib -s bitcoin -o bitcoinjs.js
```

Compilation is successful (errors don't occur).
When I try to use it in my webpage

```
function NewRandomWallet() {

    var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom()

    // Print your private key (in WIF format)
    console.log(keyPair.toWIF())
    // => Kxr9tQED9H44gCmp6HAdmemAzU3n84H3dGkuWTKvE23JgHMW8gct

    // Print your public key address
    console.log(keyPair.getAddress())
    // => 14bZ7YWde4KdRb5YN7GYkToz3EHVCvRxkF

}
```

I get followed errors in the console of Chrome:

> Unexpected token ...
>
> //because of 3 points ... in oneOf(...types) and tuple(...types) in the bitcoinjs.js file

If I remove these points I get a key and address, my code is working.
Why these points appear?

Next problem is when I try to create a transaction:

```
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder()

// Add the input (who is paying) of the form [previous transaction hash, index of the output to use]
tx.addInput("aa94ab02c182214f090e99a0d57021caffd0f195a81c24602b1028b130b63e31", 0)

// Add the output (who to pay to) of the form [payee's address, amount in satoshis]
tx.addOutput("1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK", 15000)

// Initialize a private key using WIF
var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF("L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy")

// Sign the first input with the new key
tx.sign(0, keyPair)

// Print transaction serialized as hex
console.log(tx.build().toHex())
// => 0100000001313eb630b128102b60241ca895f1d0ffca21 ...
```

I get a new error

> types.every is not a function

it's pointing to this part of the code in bitcoinjs.js

```
    function tuple(value, strict) {
      return types.every((type, i) => typeforce(type, value[i], strict));
    }
```

Any ideas? Is the code of the library wrong or I do compilation wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used browserify wrong way. 
I have compiled the bitcoinjs library with this command in CMD of Windows OS:

```
cmd> cd:testdir
cmd> npm install bitcoinjs-lib
cmd> npm -g install browserify
cmd> browserify foobar.js -o bitcoinjs.js
```

foobar.js contains:

```
Bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
```

to get minified version after use:

```
cmd> uglifyjs bitcoinjs.js -c -m -r 'Array,BigInteger,Boolean,Buffer,ECPair,Function,Number,Point,Script' -o bitcoinjs.min.js
```

if you want to get only minified version, use:

```
cmd> browserify -r bitcoinjs-lib -s Bitcoin | uglifyjs > bitcoinjs.min.js
```

Now, if you want to generate a wallet, you can do it as:

```
function NewRandomWallet() {
    var keyPair = Bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom();
    // Print your private key (in WIF format)
    $('#private_key').val(keyPair.toWIF());
    // => Kxr9tQED9H44gCmp6HAdmemAzU3n84H3dGkuWTKvE23JgHMW8gct
    // Print your public key address
    $('#address').val(keyPair.getAddress());
    // => 14bZ7YWde4KdRb5YN7GYkToz3EHVCvRxkF        
}
```

You could add a function to generate a wallet from string before minify the library:

```
ECPair.makeFromString = function (aStr) {
var hash = Bitcoin.crypto.sha256(aStr)
var d = BigInteger.fromBuffer(hash)
return new ECPair(d)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just forked bitcoinjs-lib with a compiled, minified distribution folder for your convenience.

https://github.com/davidapple/bitcoinjs-lib-for-browsers

`bower install bitcoinjs-lib-for-browsers#4.0.2 --save`

`<script src="bower_components/bitcoinjs-lib-for-browsers/dist/bitcoinjs-lib-4.0.2.min.js"></script>`